# Controlling Video Widget Position in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing around with Jupyter Notebook's ipywidgets and was wondering if there's any way to control video position (currentTime or something of that sort) using another widget or even just how to set it manually. Looking at the source code the Video widget has no way to be controlled, no currentTime property. I tried using [this widget](https://github.com/Who8MyLunch/Jupyter_Video_Widget) but it doesn't even display the video. Is there any other way or other widget to display a video and control its time/position?